# Where is "Cash Credit from Unsettled Activity" coming from?

Tags: etf, roth-ira, financial-literacy, terminology, fidelity

It's only been a month and few days since I started investing in my Roth IRA with Fidelity. Today, when I checked Portfolio Positions page, there was this thing called, "Cash Credit from Unsettled Activity". When I read its description provided by Fidelity, it's the amount of money that will come into my account on settlement date. Where is this "Cash Credit from Unsettled Activity" coming from?

I am completely new to finance world and personal investment. AGG, ITOT, IXUS, and IYR are four ETFs that I am investing in. Is "Cash Credit from Unsettled Activity" coming from any of these ETF?

Comment: Have you sold any securities recently? When you sell a security, it takes a few days for the money to "settle" in your account. Before this settlement date, Fidelity lists the proceeds from the sale as Cash Credit from Unsettled Activity. AGG issued a dividend a few days ago too.

Comment: No, I haven't made any trade this week and last week. And considering the unsettled amount, $1.17, I didn't think it was from any security trading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cash Credit from Unsettled Activity occurs because AGG [issued a dividend](http://us.ishares.com/product_info/fund/distributions/AGG.htm) in the past week. Since you purchased the ETF long enough before the record date (June 5, 2013) for that trade to settle, you qualified for a dividend. The dividend distribution was $0.195217/share for each of your six shares, for a total credit of $1.17 = 6 * 0.195217.

For any ETF, the company's website should tell you when dividends are issued, usually under a section titled "Distributions" or something similar.

If you look in your Fidelity account's History page, it should show an entry of "Dividend Received", which confirms that the cash credit is coming from a dividend distribution. You could look up your holdings and see which one(s) recently issued a dividend; in this case, it was AGG.